# Django models sorting by address

Tags: django

I need to create a model for an Event. The event must have an address so that in the future I can sort the models by address (by city). How to do it?

How to sort models by city if the address is written in one line? Or would it be better to make a separate field for the city?

```
class TeamEvent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('TeamEventDetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never able to determine a what part of an address is the street and what part is the city. That's why all forms require you to fill in both the city and address seperately. Think of the following cases when splitting the address:

1. What if a street consists of 2 seperate words?
2. What is the house number someone lives on consists of 2 seperate numbers combined?
3. What if the city consists of 2 words?

Not trying to be rude, but the best case would be to split address, house number and city seperately. Ideally you'd also have the zipcode.